# Error parsing JSON with Python, through WebSocketN: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: javascript, python, json

any troubleshooting hints on this error with parsing JSON through stdin on a python script.  Data is sent from HTML page with JavaScript, through a WebSocket.  Error is:  "ValueError:  No JSON object could be decoded."

Here is the JS code in HTML page.  I'm trying to send a simple JSON object through the WS.  Plain text goes through fine, but JSON has an issue.  On console the JS object looks just fine:

```
function saveTxt()
{

    var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
    '{ "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ] }';
    var obj1 = JSON.parse(text)

    console.log(obj1)        
    //var text1 = document.getElementById('page').textContent;
    //var obj = JSON.parse(text1)
    //ws.send(document.getElementById('page').textContent);
    //ws.send(text1);
    ws.send(obj1);
  }
```

The python script reads from stdin on a WS connection (websocketd), and it could be an issue with the Python script.

```
while True:
    line = stdin.readline().strip()
    data = json.loads(line)   

    print "Reading: " + line
    stdout.flush()
    print "Reading: %s" % data
    stdout.flush()

    myfile.write(line)
    myfile.flush()
```

Note that same code works just fine to read plain text.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to load the strings into JSON line by line. It could be seeing each line as an *individual* JSON object and errors out. To debug this, in your `while True` loop, add a `try/catch` block around `json.loads` and print out the line. You might need to add a buffer to hold the incoming lines until you get a full JSON object on the Python side, or only send complete JSON objects on the WebSocket side (the better solution in my opinion)

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I'll try to debug this.  Part of this was knowing I was sending the JSON object correctly using JS from HTML page.  The second part is whether it's an error with python code in reading the stream from stdin.  I will try debugging in loop with try/catch.  I also was attempting to understand difference between json.loads and json.load with how it is sent and supposed to be received.

Comment: Why are you constructing the JSON by hand? Use `JSON.stringify()` in the Javascript code.

Comment: The difference between `json.loads` and `json.load` is that the first takes a string, the second takes a file. `json.load(file)` is just short for `json.loads(file.read())`

Comment: Is the way I'm constructing the JSON object not correct for sending over WebSocket, when I call;

Comment: Is the way I'm constructing the JSON object not correct for sending over WebSocket, when I call JSON.parse() and send() the returned object?

Comment: When I switched to use JSON.stringify() instead of JSON.parse(), it suddenly worked with the python code parsing through stdin.  I don't know why exactly.  I thought javascript code should be creating a JSON object and sending it across the socket/WS.